# CakePHP filter paginate fields

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP v. 2.5.2, is there a simpler way to do this check?

```
if(!empty($this->passedArgs['somemodel.someatribute'])) {
    $paginate['conditions']['somemodel.someatribute'] = base64_decode($this->passedArgs['somemodel.someatribute']);
}
```

When I have many fields, the list will be very long and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Usually you should avoid passing any non-slugged non-ascii char via URLs. One should use query strings for that, they do not require additional handling (no encoding or decoding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use a standard `foreach` loop?

```
foreach($this->passedArgs as $key => $value) {
    $paginate['conditions'][$key] = base64_decode($value);
}
```

Alternatively try looking into the `$this->request->params['pass']` array, which is similar to `$this->passedArgs`.

For further details, check out [the CakePHP docs on routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html).

Comment: I edited the first part of my answer (before "Alternatively") after you marked this as correct, as the first part was wrong. I'm assuming the second part worked for you? If so I might want to remove the first part.